Google Speech API - numbers represented as digits instead of words?
While performing transcription from google speech to text API , the numbers and symbols are formatted.
I want to have the raw lexical output from API without any number formatting.
e.g. "पॉलिसी नंबर है 11173 6 2" this is my transcription generated by google
Instead of this I want transcription as "पॉलिसी नंबर है वन वन वन सेवन थ्री सिक्स टू" this should be how lexical output without number formatting should be like.
And also some symbols are automatically there like ₹564 instead of रुपये पाँच सौ चौंसठ.
How can do it to get output from API without formatting.
Tried different models like long,telephony,short but still getting same error.
